# Converting LinkedList to Arrary

Tags: java, arrays

I have a created a `LinkedList` with an `Employee` object stored in it. I need to write a method `convertToArray` that would make an array of `Employee`s by taking it from the `LinkedList`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What effort have you made so far?

Comment: Well, you can try getting the size of the linked list.. what would you do next? can you traverse the linked list? can you have an array of the same size? try something.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this is to utilize LinkedList.toArray method

```
  // create an array and copy the list to it
  Employee[] array = list.toArray(new Employee[list.size()]);
```

---

However, if you are just learning and would like to do this iteratively. Think about how you would declare and get all of the items into an array.

First, what do you need to do?

1) Declare the array of Employee's

In order to do that, you to know how big to make the array since the size of an array cannot be changed after declaration. There is a method inherited from List called .size()

```
Employee[] array = new Employee[list.size()]
```

2) For each slot in the array, copy the corresponding element in the list

To do this, you need to utilize a for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  //access element from list, assign it to array[i]
}
```

Comment: It's a minor point, but the array passed to `toArray` can be any length, including 0. `toArray` will return a newly-allocated array of the same type.

Comment: @JeffBowman If you pass in an array of the right size, the method won't have to create another one of the right size to return to you.

Comment: Fair enough. I'd forgotten that the array instance is [reused if possible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(T%5B%5D)).

Answer (score 2):

```
public <T> T[] convert (List<T> list) {
    if(list.size() == 0 ) {
        return null;
    }
    T[] array = (T[])Array.newInstance(list.get(0).getClass(), list.size());
    for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
        array[i] = list.get(i);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: i need to put it into a method where i can convert any linked list into an Array. 
    `public void convertToArray()` 
is that how i would do it?

Comment: Is this method working for you

Answer (score 1):

```
Employee[] arr = new Employee[list.size()];
int i = 0;
for(Employee e : list) {
  arr[i] = e;
  i++;
}
```